# Having trouble with R join/merge/lookup

Tags: r

I am new to R and am trying to put together a data set then create a map.

I have two data frames:

1. airports_clean

   ```
   **Airport Name   City   Country          IATA ICAO  Lat       Long**
   Goroka Airport Goroka Papua New Guinea GKA  AYGA  -6.081690 145.39200
   Madang Airport Madang Papua New Guinea MAG  AYMD  -5.207080 145.78900
   ```
2. routes_clean

   ```
   Source_IATA source_country  source_lat  source_long  Destination_IATA destination_country  destination_lat  destination_long
   ```

The only columns in routes_clean I have are source_IATA and Destination_IATA (which would be something like AER KZN respectively) which are origin and destination. I want to fill the rest of the columns with data from airports_clean.

I have tried join/merge/lookup to no avail. I think join is the correct method using IATA as the common variable between between the two datasets(they are named differently).

I used to following code to try input the source_country but I received an error message:

```
   clean_routes_01<-join(subset(routes_clean$source_country), subset(airports_clean$Country), by = ("Source_IATA"=="IATA"))
```

Any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I received the following error:

       Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must match number of columns

Comment: Your `airport_clean` data.frame does not have enough information to fill up all the columns of `routes_clean`. For example: there is only 1 set of latitude and longitude while the requirement is both for dest and source lat/long.